# Power BI Online Tenant Inventory through Powershell commands

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I'd like to know if there is any way to get a list of all reports, dashboards, and datasets that exist on a Power BI Online tenant?
Main goal to achieve here is being able to generate a full inventory [dashboards, reports, datasets, members on a given workspace]  through code e.g powershell command with related parameters, so we can clean and consolidate all the content in a given tenant. If this is possible, any hints on how to achieve this would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I googled and fond some examples here https://www.sqlshack.com/connect-query-power-bi-azure-using-powershell/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Most interesting options are available through Power BI REST API - which was first mainly perceived as an optimal solution for Power BI embedding scenarios - though looking at powershell scripts, I guess we can say Power BI REST API offers a lot more than just embedding ;).